# Credit card: did they really cancel it?

Tags: credit-card

I had a Chase MileagePlus Explorer card, which I cancelled due to numerous issues with United.  I called up and told them I wanted to cancel the card.  They confirmed, and that was that.

However, I can still log on to the website.  I can still see that I have a "$0.00 balance".  Did they really cancel (i.e. do they have a legal obligation to, and one they usually follow), or should I double-check?

Comment: Did you receive a confirmation email from them?

Comment: I suspect you can get a faster and more accurate answer from Chase customer service than from anyone here.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. - You put more stock in them than I do, it seems.

Comment: How long since you told them to cancel? I don't _know_ (since I've never cancelled a card since on-line banking existed), but it's conceivable that either (a) it takes a day or few for the process to trickle through, or (b) it remains accessible on-line for a time (perhaps until after the next statement date) in case there's a balance needing paying and/or pending transactions. Final option: they might have cancelled _that card_ (as you might do if it were stolen) but not closed the account associated with it.